# Why does bash link to ncurses?

Tags: bash, readline, ncurses

I think I've noticed this before but never thought about it much; now I'm curious.

```
> ldd /bin/bash
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2f781000)
        libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f0fdd9a9000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0fdd7a5000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0fdd3e6000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0fddbf6000)
```

Libtinfo is part of ncurses.  This is a fedora system, but it is the same on ubuntu, and I notice on raspbian (a debian variant) it also links to libncurses itself.

What's the reason for this?  I thought everything bash did could be done with libreadline (which curiously, it does not link to).  Is this simply a substitute for that?

Comment: It's part of ncurses? The package description (*shared low-level terminfo library for terminal handling*) doesn't say anything (http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libtinfo5), and it sounds reasonable for a shell to have. Maybe needed for values of `TERM`? Ah, never mind - I see the source package is `ncurses`.

Comment: `zsh` also link to libtinfo, too

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you run `bash` as:

```
LD_DEBUG=bindings bash
```

on a GNU system, and grep for `bash.*tinfo` in that output, you'll see something like:

```
   797:     binding file bash [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]: normal symbol `UP'
   797:     binding file bash [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]: normal symbol `PC'
   797:     binding file bash [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]: normal symbol `BC'
   797:     binding file bash [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]: normal symbol `tgetent'
   797:     binding file bash [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]: normal symbol `tgetstr'
   797:     binding file bash [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 [0]: normal symbol `tgetflag'
```

You can confirm from the output of `nm -D /bin/bash` that `bash` is using those symbols from tinfo.

Bringing the man page for any of those symbols clarifies what they're for:

```
$ man tgetent
NAME
   PC, UP, BC, ospeed, tgetent, tgetflag, tgetnum, tgetstr, tgoto, tputs -
   direct curses interface to the terminfo capability database
```

Basically, `bash`, more likely its `readline` (libreadline is statically linked in) editor, uses those to query the terminfo database to find out about terminal capabilities so it can run its line editor properly (sending the right escape sequences and identify key presses correctly) on any terminal.

As to why readline is statically linked into `bash`, you have to bear in mind that `readline` is developed alongside `bash` by the same person and is included in the source of `bash`.

It is possible to build `bash` to be linked with the system's installed `libreadline`, but only if that one is of a compatible version, and that's not the default. You need to call the `configure` script at compilation time with `--with-installed-readline`.

Answer (score 3):

`bash` is a [*termcap* application](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#uses_of_library) via `readline`, like `screen` and some other programs.  On most Linux-based systems (aside from Slackware), you're likely to see ncurses as underlying implementation of *termcap*.

The [manual page for `tgetent`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_termcap.3x.html) (named **curs_termcap** because that's the way it was done in SVr4...) says:

> These  routines  are included as a conversion aid for programs that use the *termcap* library.  Their parameters  are
>   the  same and the routines are emulated using the *terminfo*
>   database.  Thus, they can only be used to query the  capabilities  of  entries  for which a *terminfo* entry has been
>   compiled.

That is, if the calling program does not look closely at the data returned, and uses the conventional termcap interface for reading the terminal description and writing data to the screen, it works just like the original termcap.

Most termcap applications don't look that closely (xterm is a rare exception — [see FAQ](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#no_termcap)).  So `bash` works with ncurses.

However, the termcap library is smaller than ncurses.  Quite a while ago that mattered, and [since 1997](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t971220) ncurses has had a configure option `--with-termlib` which makes it build the termcap- and terminfo-specific parts as a library separate from the functions needed in the higher-level curses library.  A few years passed, and some of the Linux-based distributions incorporated that into their packages.

Since `bash` doesn't use any of the curses functions (libncurses, etc.), it's reasonable to link only against the `libtinfo`.

`readline` is the termcap-specific part of `bash` (actually when I first encountered `bash`, its termcap parts were ***hardcoded***, even though the official source used termcap — perhaps to save a few more bytes).  When `bash` is built with the bundled `readline`, you will not see `readline` as a separate library because there would be no point in making that bundled `readline` install as a (possibly conflicting) shared library.  But (depending on your system), you may see `libtinfo` because ncurses is built one way or the other (split or not) — not both.